# Why AppleScript doesn't enter Repeat loop

Tags: while-loop, applescript

My overall goal is to close Avast window during start up. Performing this repeat until loop does not trigger the code within the loop.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set ids to bundle identifier of every application process
    repeat until ids contains "com.avast.AAFM"
        wait(1)
        beep
        set ids to bundle identifier of every application process
    end repeat
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Avast" to tell the front window to if (exists) then tell attribute "AXCloseButton" to click its value
end tell
```

Using a clumsy brute force approach to check if com.avast.AAFM is one of the apps open before quitting. If not then wait a second and check again. I'm not understanding why the repeat loop isn't run. When Avast is running the script does close Avast.

Answer (score 0):

Is `wait` a valid AppleScript command?

In this case I'd prefer a simple `repeat` loop and `exit repeat`

```
repeat
    tell application "System Events" to set ids to bundle identifier of every application process
    if ids contains "com.avast.AAFM" then exit repeat
    delay 1
    beep
end repeat 
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Avast" to tell the front window to if (exists) then tell attribute "AXCloseButton" to click its value
```

Comment: I hit enter too soon.
Detecting then quitting the app works when the app is open (foremost window or not). It's the repeat/end repeat that doesn't run. It seems to execute one then ends. The beep is evidence that the loop is entered but no beep.

The script was added to the Login Items in Users & Groups. When the laptop starts the script is visible but the Avast screen is one of the last items to appear and stays there. The script ended already.

Answer (score 0):

You can close (*on startup*) any application windows simpler:

```
set appID to "com.avast.AAFM"

repeat until window 1 of application id appID exists
    delay 1
end repeat

tell application id appID to close windows
```